# How to identify GPU memory bottleneck in chainer

Tags: chainer

I have a chainer model which sometimes crash due to `cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError`. As the exact emplacement where it happens depends on the size of the elements of the batch, I was wondering if there is a way to identify memory bottlenecks in a chainer model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer `CupyMemoryProfileHook`.

- https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/function_hooks/cupy_memory_profile.py#L17

> ```
>     Code example::
>         from chainer.function_hooks import CupyMemoryProfileHook
>         hook = CupyMemoryProfileHook()
>         with hook:
>             trainer.run()
>         hook.print_report()
>     Output example::
>                FunctionName  UsedBytes  AcquiredBytes  Occurrence
>              LinearFunction     5.16GB       179.98MB        3900
>                        ReLU   991.82MB       458.97MB        2600
>         SoftmaxCrossEntropy     7.71MB         5.08MB        1300
>                    Accuracy   617.97KB       351.00KB         700
> ```